# Cannot launch any activity except the launcher activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

first question on StackExchange so I hope you can forgive me for my mistakes.

I am developing an app which is a csipsimple project fork. But whenever I try to launch an activity with intent or an activity launcher app, the app crashes.

Here is the stack trace when I try to launch activities (It is same for any activity except for SplashActivity which is launcher activity and runs fine.):

EDIT FOR ERROR (Accidentally removed the manifest entry but problem persists.)

```
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827): Process: com.myapp.client, PID: 5827
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.client/com.myapp.client.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:143)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at com.myapp.client.db.MySQLProvider.<init>(MySQLProvider.java:65)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at com.myapp.client.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:69)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
07-21 15:33:18.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     ... 11 more
```

Following code is my SplashActivity.java that calls LoginActivity.java

```
package com.myapp.client;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    protected boolean _active = true;
    protected int _splashTime = 3000; // time to display the splash screen in ms




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        else
        {
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            // Hide the status bar.
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions); 
        }
        defaultAccount();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);



        Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    while (_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                        sleep(100);
                        if (_active) {
                            waited += 100;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                } finally {

                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                            LoginActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            };
                 };
        splashTread.start();
    }
    private void defaultAccount(){
        PreferencesProviderWrapper prefwrap = new PreferencesProviderWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        if (prefwrap.getPreferenceBooleanValue("initialrun", true))
        {
            //Set the default account
            PreferencesWrapper prefs = new PreferencesWrapper(getApplicationContext());

            WizardInfo wizardInfo = WizardUtils.getWizardClass("myapp");
            WizardIface wizard = null;
            try {
                wizard = (WizardIface) wizardInfo.classObject.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                Log.e("myapp", "Can't access wizard class", e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("myapp", "Can't access wizard class", e);
            }


            prefwrap.setPreferenceBooleanValue("initialrun", false);
            SipProfile account = SipProfile.getProfileFromDbId(this, SipProfile.INVALID_ID, DBProvider.ACCOUNT_FULL_PROJECTION);
            account = wizard.buildAccount(account);
            prefs.startEditing();
            wizard.setDefaultParams(prefs);
            prefs.endEditing();
            account.display_name = "myapp Account";
            account.username= "REDACTED";
            account.wizard = "myapp";
            account = wizard.buildAccount(account);

            account.acc_id = "REDACTED";
            account.reg_uri = "REDACTED";

            account.datatype=0;
            account.data="REDACTED";
            account.use_rfc5626 = true;
            if(true) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(account.rfc5626_instance_id)) {
                    String autoInstanceId = (UUID.randomUUID()).toString();
                    account.rfc5626_instance_id = "<urn:uuid:"+autoInstanceId+">";
                }
            }
            Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(SipProfile.ACCOUNT_URI, account.getDbContentValues());
            account.id = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
            List<Filter> filters = wizard.getDefaultFilters(account);
            if (filters != null) {
                for (Filter filter : filters) {
                    // Ensure the correct id if not done by the wizard
                    filter.account = (int) account.id;
                    getContentResolver().insert(SipManager.FILTER_URI, filter.getDbContentValues());
                }
            }


    }}


}
```

And then here is my LoginActivity.java

```
package com.myapp.client;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    MySQLProvider loginProvider;
    Map<String,String> siplogin = null;
    EditText username;
    EditText password;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        else
        {
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            // Hide the status bar.
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions); 
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username1);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password1);
        loginProvider= new MySQLProvider(LoginActivity.this);

    }
    public void loginSubmit(View view){
        int responseRecieved = generateResponse();
        if (responseRecieved == 0){
            setSipLogin(siplogin);
        }
        generateDialog(responseRecieved);
    }
    private int generateResponse(){
        loginProvider.sqlConnect();
        Map<String,String> logininfo = null;
        ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        if (!isConnected){return 3;}
        if (username.getText().toString() != "" && password.getText().toString() != ""){
            logininfo = loginProvider.getLoginInfo(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
        }
        else return 2;
        if (logininfo.isEmpty() || logininfo == null){
            return 1;
        }
        siplogin = logininfo;
        return 0;

    }
    private void generateDialog(int response){
        switch (response){
        case 0:

            break;
        case 1:
             AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
             alertDialog.setTitle("myapp Login");
             alertDialog.setMessage("Username or password is not correct. Please try again.");
             alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new Message());
             alertDialog.show();

            break;
        case 2:
             AlertDialog alertDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
             alertDialog1.setTitle("myapp Login");
             alertDialog1.setMessage("Please fill the required fields.");
             alertDialog1.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new Message());
             alertDialog1.show();

            break;
        case 3:
             AlertDialog alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
             alertDialog2.setTitle("myapp Login");
             alertDialog2.setMessage("Please provide internet connectivity");
             alertDialog2.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new Message());
             alertDialog2.show();

             break;
        }


    }
    private void setSipLogin(Map<String,String> siplogin){

        PreferencesProviderWrapper prefwrap = new PreferencesProviderWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        //if (prefwrap.getPreferenceBooleanValue("initialrun", true))
        //{
            //Set the default account(disabled)
            PreferencesWrapper prefs = new PreferencesWrapper(getApplicationContext());

            WizardInfo wizardInfo = WizardUtils.getWizardClass("myapp");
            WizardIface wizard = null;
            try {
                wizard = (WizardIface) wizardInfo.classObject.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                Log.e("myapp", "Can't access wizard class", e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("myapp", "Can't access wizard class", e);
            }


            //prefwrap.setPreferenceBooleanValue("initialrun", false);
            SipProfile account = SipProfile.getProfileFromDbId(this, 1, DBProvider.ACCOUNT_FULL_PROJECTION);
            account = wizard.buildAccount(account);
            prefs.startEditing();
            wizard.setDefaultParams(prefs);
            prefs.endEditing();
            String[] sipLoginParsed = siplogin.get("info").split(Pattern.quote("#|#|#|#"));
            account.display_name = "myapp Account";
            account.username= sipLoginParsed[0];
            account.wizard = "myapp";
            account = wizard.buildAccount(account);

            account.acc_id = "REDACTED";
            account.reg_uri = "REDACTED";

            account.datatype=0;
            account.data=sipLoginParsed[1];
            account.use_rfc5626 = true;
            if(true) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(account.rfc5626_instance_id)) {
                    String autoInstanceId = (UUID.randomUUID()).toString();
                    account.rfc5626_instance_id = "<urn:uuid:"+autoInstanceId+">";
                }
            }
            Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(SipProfile.ACCOUNT_URI, account.getDbContentValues());
            account.id = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
            List<Filter> filters = wizard.getDefaultFilters(account);
            if (filters != null) {
                for (Filter filter : filters) {
                    // Ensure the correct id if not done by the wizard
                    filter.account = (int) account.id;
                    getContentResolver().insert(SipManager.FILTER_URI, filter.getDbContentValues());
                }
            }

            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,SipHome.class));

        }


    }


//}
```

And finally here is my Android Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.myapp.client"
        android:installLocation="auto"
        android:versionCode="2459"
        android:versionName="1.02.03" >


        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="7"
            android:targetSdkVersion="22" />  

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:backupAgent=".backup.SipBackupAgent"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_nightly"
            android:label="myapp" >

            <!--


            <activity
                android:name=".ui.SipHome"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme"
                android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
                <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
                    <action android:name="com.myapp.client.phone.action.DIALER" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data android:scheme="sip" />
                    <data android:scheme="csip" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
                    <action android:name="com.myapp.client.phone.action.CALLLOG" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
                    <action android:name="com.myapp.client.phone.action.FAVORITES" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
                    <action android:name="com.myapp.client.phone.action.MESSAGES" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity-alias
                android:name=".ui.SipDialer"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:targetActivity=".ui.SipHome"
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme"
                android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                    <data android:scheme="csip" />
                    <data android:scheme="sip" />
                    <data android:scheme="sips" />
                    <data android:scheme="sms" />
                    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                    <data
                        android:host="csip"
                        android:scheme="imto" />
                    <data
                        android:host="sip"
                        android:scheme="imto" />
                    <data
                        android:host="skype"
                        android:scheme="imto" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity-alias>

            <!-- Main service -->
            <!-- Require at least the configure permission to use -->
            <service
                android:name=".service.SipService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:permission="android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP"
                android:process=":sipStack" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.myapp.client.service.SipService" />
                    <action android:name="com.myapp.client.service.SipConfiguration" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
            <service android:name=".service.Downloader" />

            <!-- Main ui -->
            <activity
                android:name=".ui.calllog.CallLogDetailsActivity"
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme" />


                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".ui.prefs.cupcake.MainPrefs"
                android:configChanges="orientation"
                android:enabled="@bool/use_cupcake_prefs"
                android:label="@string/prefs"
                android:permission="android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP"
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.myapp.client.ui.action.PREFS_GLOBAL" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".ui.prefs.cupcake.PrefsLoaderActivity"
                android:label=""
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme" />
            <activity
                android:name=".ui.prefs.PrefsFilters"
                android:configChanges="orientation"
                android:label="@string/filters"
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme" />
            <activity
                android:name=".ui.prefs.PrefsFast"
                android:configChanges="orientation"
                android:label="@string/prefs_fast"
                android:permission="android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP"
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme.Dialog" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.myapp.client.ui.action.PREFS_FAST" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".ui.prefs.Codecs"
                android:configChanges="orientation"
                android:label="@string/codecs"
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme" />
            <activity
                android:name=".ui.prefs.AudioTester"
                android:label="@string/test_audio"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme.Dialog" />

            <!-- Wizards -->
            <activity
                android:name=".wizards.BasePrefsWizard"
                android:configChanges="orientation"
                android:label="@string/edit"
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme" />

            <!-- Call management -->
            <receiver
                android:name=".service.OutgoingCall"
                android:permission="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
                android:process=":sipStack" >

                <!-- Here filter for protected-broadcasts -->
                <intent-filter android:priority="0" >
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <activity
                android:name=".ui.outgoingcall.OutgoingCallChooser"
                android:allowTaskReparenting="false"
                android:configChanges="orientation"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:label="@string/call"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:permission="android.permission.USE_SIP"
                android:process=":sipStack"
                android:taskAffinity=""
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme.Dialog" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data android:scheme="csip" />
                    <data android:scheme="sip" />
                    <data android:scheme="sips" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
                    <action android:name="android.phone.extra.NEW_CALL_INTENT" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data android:scheme="csip" />
                    <data android:scheme="sip" />
                    <data android:scheme="sips" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity-alias
                android:name=".ui.PrivilegedOutgoingSipCallBroadcaster"
                android:configChanges="orientation"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:permission="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"
                android:targetActivity=".ui.outgoingcall.OutgoingCallChooser"
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme.Dialog" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data android:scheme="sip" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity-alias>
            <activity-alias
                android:name=".ui.PrivilegedOutgoingCallBroadcaster"
                android:configChanges="orientation"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:label="@string/sip_call"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:permission="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"
                android:targetActivity=".ui.outgoingcall.OutgoingCallChooser"
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme.Dialog" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data android:scheme="tel" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone" />
                    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2" />
                    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                    <data android:scheme="sms" />
                    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity-alias>

            <!-- To be able to do video, this has to be launched in sipStack process -->
            <activity
                android:name=".ui.incall.InCallActivity"
                android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
                android:configChanges="orientation"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:permission="android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP"
                android:process=":sipStack"
                android:taskAffinity=""
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme.NoTitle" >
                <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
                    <action android:name="com.myapp.client.phone.action.INCALL" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".ui.PickupSipUri"
                android:configChanges="orientation"
                android:label="@string/pickup_sip_uri"
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme" />
            <activity
                android:name=".ui.incall.InCallMediaControl"
                android:configChanges="orientation"
                android:label="@string/prefs_media"
                android:taskAffinity="com.myapp.client.ui.incall.InCallActivity"
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme.Dialog" />




            <!-- New UI -->
            <activity
                android:name=".ui.account.AccountsEditList"
                android:label="@string/accounts"
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme" />
            <activity
                android:name=".ui.account.AccountEdit"
                android:theme="@style/DarkTheme" />


            <activity
                android:name=".SplashActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:noHistory="true"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="LoginActivity" />

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Android Manifest and some parts of code is redacted for 30000 chars.(Receivers and providers also imports)
Same error also occurs when I try to launch any activity from activity launcher app.

Comment: The error is caused by something in MySQLProvider line 65 but with the logs cannot determine it.

Comment: Problably your `LoginActivity` activity in the manifest hasn't define a theme. Try to specify some one.

Comment: First one solved the error, it was a declatarion error for progressdialog. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing to declare LoginActivity in your Manifest.

```
<activity
android:name=".LoginActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:label="LoginActivity" />
```

There's simply no way to start an Activity if it is not declared.

Comment: Did you change your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Like you pointed out, I think the error occurs because LoginActivity is not included as an Activity in your AndroidManifest